# Sorting structure variables(3 ints) in file from smallest to largest C

Tags: c, function, file, sorting

I need to sort my 2 text files for my project. One of the text files is in student id, course id and score format and the other is in student id's format. I wrote the values in both of them with fprintf, so I am using fscanf while reading, but my function is not working correctly, can you tell me where is my mistake?

(I deleted the old code that didn't work because I continued on a different code)

Edit :I tried to create a code snippet based on the solution below, but when I enter the while loop, fscanf starts to get the wrong numbers. Can you look for where my mistake is?

Edit :After editing here, I did the fopen checks. There is no problem with them. The while loop closes after it runs once, I think, in the if fscanf parts, fscanf does not read the number correctly, so it exits the loop with break.

most likely broken part:

```
    FILE *index = fopen("index.txt", "r");
    FILE *record = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    if (!index)
        return;
    if (!record)
        return;
    int array[n][3];
    //int *array = (int *)malloc(n *3 sizeof(int));???
    int count = 0;
    int i=0,temp,id,course,score;
    while (1)
    {  
        if(count==n) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &id) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &course) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &score) != 1) break;
        array[count][0] = id;
        array[count][1] = course;
        array[count][2] = score;
        count++;
    }
```

the rest of the function for you to browse if the error is elsewhere:

```
void sort_for_bin_search(int n)
{
    FILE *index = fopen("index.txt", "r");
    FILE *record = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    if (!index)
        return;
    if (!record)
        return;
    int array[n][3];
    //int *array = (int *)malloc(n *3 sizeof(int));???
    int count = 0;
    int i=0,temp,id,course,score;
    while (1)
    {  
        if(count==n) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &id) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &course) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(record, "%d", &score) != 1) break;
        array[count][0] = id;
        array[count][1] = course;
        array[count][2] = score;
        count++;
    }
     for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if(array[i][0] > array [j][0])
            {
            temp=array[j][0];
            array[j][0] = array[i][0];
            array[i][0] = temp;

            temp=array[j][1];
            array[j][1] = array[i][1];
            array[i][1] = temp;

            temp=array[j][2];
            array[j][2] = array[i][2];
            array[i][2] = temp;
            }
            else if((array[i][0]==array[j][0])&&(array[i][1]>array[j][1]))
            {
            temp=array[j][0];
            array[j][0] = array[i][0];
            array[i][0] = temp;

            temp=array[j][1];
            array[j][1] = array[i][1];
            array[i][1] = temp;

            temp=array[j][2];
            array[j][2] = array[i][2];
            array[i][2] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
    fclose(record);
    fclose(index);
    FILE *index2 = fopen("index.txt", "w");
    FILE *record2 = fopen("record.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(index2,"%d\n",array[i][0]);
        fprintf(record2,"%d %d %d\n",array[i][0],array[i][1],array[i][2]);
        //printf("%d %d %d\n",array[i][0],array[i][1],array[i][2]);
    }
    //free(array);
    fclose(record2);
    fclose(index2);
}
```

Comment: You absolutely need to check if `fopen` fails

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does "is not working correctly" mean? Please provide your input, output and expected output. If you get any error messages, which are they?

Comment: Your approach is wrong, your usage of `fseek` doesn't make sense with text files. You also should process reading from the files, sorting and writing to the files separately and not doing all three simulaneously

Comment: `fseek(record,  3*sizeof(int) * j, SEEK_SET);` You are calculating size in bytes, not text representation. As Jabberwocky wrote, `fseek` and text files don't go together very well.

Comment: I'm new to file operations, if I can't use it like this, what would you recommend I use instead?

Comment: Even after your edits the very first comment is still relevant. Check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: Please post shortened versions of of your text files as properly formatted text and show the output you get vs. the output you want. We need a [mcve] read this closely.

Comment: After editing here, I did the fopen checks. There is no problem with them. The while loop closes after it runs once, I think, in the if fscanf parts, fscanf does not read the number correctly, so it exits the loop with break.

Comment: I'm really sorry for missing edits. I'm new to this type of forum use and coding world as well as to the site. I am trying to get used to. I would appreciate it if you would excuse my mistakes.@Jabberwocky

Comment: @Yodax93 no need to excuse, but please post the shortened versions of of your text files. Also read this: [ask] before posting your next question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are doing a bubble sort, and in each iteration you read/write from disk. Disk operations are very slow. It is much easier and faster if you read once in to array. And then sort that single array.

Example:

```
void sort_for_bin_search(int n)
{
    //assumes that `n` is the number of lines in this file
    if (n < 1) return;
    FILE* fin = fopen("index.txt", "r");
    if (!fin)
        return;
    FILE* fout = fopen("record.txt", "w");
    if (!fout)
        return;

    int* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr) return;
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (count == n)
            break;
        int id, course, score;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &id) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &course) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &score) != 1) break;
        arr[count] = id;
        count++;
    }
    //add code for sorting arr
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fprintf(fout, "%d\n", arr[i]);

    free(arr);
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Then you can sort, for example using bubble sort.

Use `printf` to print the data on screen at each step, this will help with debugging.

```
void sort_for_bin_search(int n)
{
    FILE* fin = fopen("input_file.txt", "r");
    if (!fin)
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return;
    }
    int array[n][3];
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int id, course, score;
        if (count == n) break;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &id) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &course) != 1) break;
        if (fscanf(fin, "%d", &score) != 1) break;
        array[count][0] = id;
        array[count][1] = course;
        array[count][2] = score;
        count++;
    }
    n = count;
    printf("reading:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);

    printf("\nsort\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j][0] > array[j + 1][0])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = array[j][0];
                array[j][0] = array[j + 1][0];
                array[j + 1][0] = temp;

                temp = array[j][1];
                array[j][1] = array[j + 1][1];
                array[j + 1][1] = temp;

                temp = array[j][2];
                array[j][2] = array[j + 1][2];
                array[j + 1][2] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);

    printf("sorted\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);

    printf("write to file\n");
    FILE* fout = fopen("output_file.txt", "w");
    if(!fout)
    {
        printf("output error\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fprintf(fout, "%d %d %d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: Since they didn't teach us about recursion yet, they especially wanted to use bubble sort or binary sort, I chose bubble sort because it was easier.

Comment: @Yodax93 Ignore `qsort`, I just put that there to quickly test the code. You should be able to rewrite your code for bubble sort on the array `arr`.

Comment: I changed the code a bit and integrated it into my project, but inside the while loop the code starts to break, and as a result, the array starts returning very strange numbers. Can you look for where the error is?

Comment: I can't figure out which one is  your input file and which one is output. I renamed the file. Use the right name, and print the array on screen at each step. There seems to be a problem with your bubble-sort as well, I replaced it, by my version. You should really start with a 1-D array before moving to 3-D array.